# car engine wont start and randomly turns off while driving

Tags: engine, ford, ignition, focus

so i drive a ford focus lx 2000 (i dont know anything about cars) and sometimes it wont start. like when i turn the key, the lights, ac and radio turn on but the engine doesnt even click or make anytype of noise. sometimes the engine will even turn off while im driving which is dangerous and everything else stays on. hiting the fuse box does sometimes work to turn it on. sometimes it takes one try sometimes it can take ten minutes. so yeah, i dont know what the heck is wrong

Comment: Sounds like an electrical issue, especially when you mention hitting the fuse box sometimes fixes it and when it does not start there is not even a click. Its like the starter and ignition are not getting power at all. Perhaps a bad wire somewhere.

Comment: Do you (or does anyone you know) have access to a voltmeter (or multimeter)? As @Chris said, this sounds electrical, but electrical issues still require a decent amount of diagnosing. A multimeter will *really* help with this process, since we can use it to test battery voltage, alternator voltage, ground continuity, fuse continuity, etc.

Comment: Is there any rust on the battery terminals or on any wires around the fuse box area? Sounds like a bad connection to me, and rust could be the culprit if it works after smacking it, that or maybe a loose connection somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I'd investigate the ignition switch or the ignition relay. You can test this the next time it fails by twisting the key back and forth slighty.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few basic list of things you have to check

1. battery
2. fuel pump
3. fuel system (filter lines for clogs, fuel rail for any minor leaks)
4. engine ground
5. ign coil
6. coil wire
7. broken battery wires